# Using POST to hide confidential data in Spring Data Rest @Query method

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

The below JPA Repository is exposed using Spring Data Rest via Http GET method - which in practice is correct, however, in my case it's revealing / sending password info via GET rather a Web Form. Is there a way to force use a POST instead?

The URL for below is:
http://localhost:8080/api/users/search/queryForLogin?email=myemail@xyz.com&password=myPass

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

@Query("select u from User u where lower(u.email) = lower(:email) and 
u.password = :password")
User queryForLogin( 
                @Param("email") String email,
                @Param("password") String password );
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a POST would be better than a GET?

Comment: To conceal password/confidential data getting sent bare...

Comment: But even if you are using POST over HTTP username and password are sent in plain text. You should use HTTPS and then why not use basic authentication and spring security?